# Calling a compiled C++ Executable from PHP to Create Socket

Tags: php, c++, apache, centos

I'm working on a web application that uses both C++ and PHP.
The issue at hand revolves around calling a CPP executable from PHP.

Environment:

- CentOS7
- PHP 7.4 (Remi)
- Apache 2.4.6
- C++ 11

Apache runs as apache:[appgroup], and all files are owned by the same.  Executable files are executable by owner and group.

However, calling the executable from php -- whether using exec(), shell_exec(), or system() -- doesn't work, despite the code working when called from the command line.

I've done some testing by running

```php
echo exec("whoami");
var_dump(file_exists('/var/www/html/project/bin/main'));
var_dump(is_executable('/var/www/html/project/bin/main'));
```

(With main being a compiled C++ file, that exists, that works when called from the command line). PHP can see the file, but "is_executable" returns false. "Whoami" returns apache, as expected.

I've messed with httpd.conf, php.ini, and tried calling the file several different ways. I've created shell and "hello world" C++ files, placed them in the same directory as the php script, and still had no luck.

No matter what, the following line will not do anything (nor will any call to any other C++ executable or shell script).

```php
exec("/var/www/html/project/bin/main > /dev/null 2>&1");
```

What is stopping this from working?

Comment: Calling executables from web application doesn't look too secure. Are you sure some SELinux or AppArmor is not preventing you from doing such risky thing?

Comment: Instead of redirecting all the output to `/dev/null`, return it to the PHP script so you can report the error.

Comment: The default in CentOS 7 is to run your Apache HTTP Daemon inside a chroot jail. Therefore, the full path of `/var/www/ ... etc.` may not exist from your PHP code's perspective, or may have a physical location different than you expect. Try running it from a relative path within the Document Root. E.g., assuming it is possible to visit `http://yourdomain.com/project/index.php` because file `/var/www/html/project/index.php` exists, try running exec for `./project/bin/main`.

Comment: @barmar it does not return an error, even when output is not redirected.

Comment: @jaroslawj it looks like SELinux may have been to blame.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling executables from web application doesn't look too secure. Are you sure some SELinux or AppArmor is not preventing you from doing such risky thing?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer (and in fact you did post this as comment before). If the answer to your question is "yes", then please rephrase this as an answer based on that fact, not as an open question. As it's written right now, your answer should be deleted, even with OP having accepted it.